# How to translate Lookup values in Django?

Tags: django, internationalization

Django has an excellent support for internationalization, any English expression within Models, Forms, View or template can easily be marked for translation. However I came across an interesting situation I don't know how to deal with.

I have a Gender lookup (Male, Female). Now even if I translated the site into German, the Gender dropdown is still pointing to the values saved in database, which happens to be in English. So How am I supposed to mark the values in the database to be translated in PO files?

```
class Gender(models.Model):
    gender       = models.CharField(_(u'Sex'), max_length=10)    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.gender
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _(u'Sex')
        verbose_name_plural = _(u'Sexes')
```

Many Thanks,

Comment: Hi Kave, i think thats not possbile. You will have to use one of those translation modules (like http://code.google.com/p/django-modeltranslation/) or write your own translation functions.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I can't really see if the project is still alive. But I will give it a shot and report back here. Why don't they put it on GitHub? :) You can put this as an answer in the meanwhile. Thanks

Comment: The project is alive, i happened to move modeltranslation to github this week. BTW, just because something isn't on github it is not necessarily dead. ;)

Comment: haha thanks Dirk.  I am actually using django-modeltranslation in my project. It works nicely, Many thanks. One last question, is there any quick way to create SQL insert commands from my db translations for the production database? Then I could simply run that sql on the production db and get the model translations in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think thats not possbile. You will have to use one of those translation modules (like [code.google.com/p/django-modeltranslation](http://code.google.com/p/django-modeltranslation)) or write your own translation functions.